# Zurb Foundation Top Bar 'min-height" wrong

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I am in the process of using Foundation to create a website, and I have come across a problem that I can't seem to find the solution too. I have noticed that when expanded, some of my drop-downs get cut off in the Mobile Version of the Top Bar, and I was wondering if anyone had come across this issue, or had a fix for it. Did I do something in the CSS that made the JS no longer count all of the elements correctly?

You can see what I am saying here.
http://www2.100foldstudio.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that if I add a List Item at the end of the main top bar section in "mobile" mode, and added a clearfix class to it, the js kicked in and started calculating the height correctly.

Thanks guys,

Answer (score 0):

Just try this by adding in css.

```
.jScrollPaneDrag {
height:0px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the link is break in theme

Update the link from

```
http://www2.100foldstudio.org/wp-content/themes/100foldstudio/_/js/functions.js
```

to

```
http://www2.100foldstudio.org/wp-content/themes/100foldstudio/js/functions.js
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to change that, but it's just the remnants of an old functions file.  It's an unfinished and unpolished theme so far.  That wasn't the issue in concern though.

Comment: You should remove the link to the JS or update it so you're not getting a 404 error though, this could have some strange cascading effects later down the line.